# DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION BSOD

Tags: drivers, bsod

I am having an issue with a driver (I think). I think that it is the Wacom Driver for their Intous Draw pen tablet. That was the driver that was most recently installed.

Blue Screen View Reports this:

```
122515-26421-01.dmp 25/12/2015 13:33:57 DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION  0x000000c4  00000000`000000d2   ffffe001`9c1ab3c0   ffffe001`9c1ab000   00000000`00000b30   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+142760 NT Kernel & System  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   10.0.10586.17 (th2_release.151121-2308) x64 ntoskrnl.exe+142760                 C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\122515-26421-01.dmp 8   15  10586   299,076 25/12/2015 13:35:14
```

---

WinDbg reports this:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION (c4)
A device driver attempting to corrupt the system has been caught.  This is
because the driver was specified in the registry as being suspect (by the
administrator) and the kernel has enabled substantial checking of this driver.
If the driver attempts to corrupt the system, bugchecks 0xC4, 0xC1 and 0xA will
be among the most commonly seen crashes.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000000000d2, Freeing pool allocation that contains active ERESOURCE.
Arg2: ffffe0019c1ab3c0, ERESOURCE address.
Arg3: ffffe0019c1ab000, Pool allocation start address.
Arg4: 0000000000000b30, Pool allocation size.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.17.amd64fre.th2_release.151121-2308

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  GP60 2PE

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  REV:1.0

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  E16GHIMS.10A

BIOS_DATE:  07/19/2014

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  MS-16GH

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  REV:1.0

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: d2

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffe0019c1ab3c0

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffe0019c1ab000

BUGCHECK_P4: b30

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xc4_d2

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: 95a

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3c,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1E'00000000 (cache) 1E'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VERIFIER_ENABLED_VISTA_MINIDUMP

PROCESS_NAME:  sniffer.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  ALEXMSI

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  12-25-2015 13:44:21.0174

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8002fed0298 to fffff8002f953760

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`21d57098 fffff800`2fed0298 : 00000000`000000c4 00000000`000000d2 ffffe001`9c1ab3c0 ffffe001`9c1ab000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd000`21d570a0 fffff800`2fed9869 : ffffe001`9c1ab000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 ffffe001`a2118010 : nt!VerifierBugCheckIfAppropriate+0x3c
ffffd000`21d570e0 fffff800`2fa1fb63 : ffffe001`9c1ab000 00000000`00000b30 00000000`00000000 fffff800`2fa20485 : nt!VfCheckForResource+0x99
ffffd000`21d57130 fffff800`2fa42d32 : ffffe001`9c1ab000 00000000`00000b30 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!ExpCheckForResource+0x3b
ffffd000`21d57180 fffff800`2fbe31f0 : 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`9c1ab030 00000000`00000000 00000000`00010282 : nt!ExFreePool+0x212
ffffd000`21d57260 fffff800`2f861d2f : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffd000`21d57380 ffffe001`9c1ab080 : nt!ObpRemoveObjectRoutine+0x80
ffffd000`21d572c0 fffff800`2f8f98ce : 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`9ff7f080 00000000`00002500 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObfDereferenceObjectWithTag+0xbf
ffffd000`21d57300 fffff800`2f8f9770 : 00000000`00000000 ffffd000`21d57400 ffffe001`9c1ab080 00000000`00000001 : nt!IopCompleteUnloadOrDelete+0xa6
ffffd000`21d573c0 fffff800`a9d5b908 : ffffe001`9c1ab260 ffffd000`21d574f0 ffffe001`9c1ab330 ffffe001`9c1ab2c8 : nt!IoDeleteDevice+0x9c
ffffd000`21d573f0 ffffe001`9c1ab260 : ffffd000`21d574f0 ffffe001`9c1ab330 ffffe001`9c1ab2c8 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x3b908
ffffd000`21d573f8 ffffd000`21d574f0 : ffffe001`9c1ab330 ffffe001`9c1ab2c8 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`a26dbe00 : 0xffffe001`9c1ab260
ffffd000`21d57400 ffffe001`9c1ab330 : ffffe001`9c1ab2c8 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`a26dbe00 fffff800`aa3a1f00 : 0xffffd000`21d574f0
ffffd000`21d57408 ffffe001`9c1ab2c8 : 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`a26dbe00 fffff800`aa3a1f00 00000000`00000000 : 0xffffe001`9c1ab330
ffffd000`21d57410 00000000`00000000 : ffffe001`a26dbe00 fffff800`aa3a1f00 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`9c1ab080 : 0xffffe001`9c1ab2c8


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  06b6987d4c99dc523c7f92c9be40167bd170e761

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  93bfefae0c082cb5453842be55e5d5ea7f425918

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  dc00c0cff3a932fa7cb8530264bdac8f7360e60e

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nvlddmkm+3b908
fffff800`a9d5b908 488d0dd15fa100  lea     rcx,[nvlddmkm+0xa518e0 (fffff800`aa7718e0)]

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  d10d8d48

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  9

SYMBOL_NAME:  nvlddmkm+3b908

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nvlddmkm

IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  56716f32

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  3b908

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xc4_d2_VRF_nvlddmkm!Unknown_Function

BUCKET_ID:  0xc4_d2_VRF_nvlddmkm!Unknown_Function

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0xc4_d2_VRF_nvlddmkm!Unknown_Function

TARGET_TIME:  2015-12-25T19:33:57.000Z

OSBUILD:  10586

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2015-11-22 03:24:24

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  151121-2308

BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.17.amd64fre.th2_release.151121-2308

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 2c9f

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0xc4_d2_vrf_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {e8bca772-3986-cbe0-6429-da0a904eff24}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

2: kd> lmvm nvlddmkm
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff800`a9d20000 fffff800`aa93b000   nvlddmkm T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: nvlddmkm.sys
    Image path: nvlddmkm.sys
    Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Wed Dec 16 08:03:30 2015 (56716F32)
    CheckSum:         00BE13AE
    ImageSize:        00C1B000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

The issue appear to happen when I open Adobe Photoshop. The Wacom driver is the latest version.

Comment: You have the current Intel display drivers installed?  I see zero evidence to point to Wacom drivers being at fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the Intel Display driver to 20.19.15.4331 and updating Photoshop has solved the issue.

Comment: the dumps shows nvlddmkm.sys which is the nVIDIA driver. So also update this driver